# How to direct a page from a form Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, view

I am working on a dictionary app, i am allowing a user to enter a word through a form. When the word is entered in the form and a submit button is pressed i want the form to be maintained on the same page however when the user enter the word and presses submit the form disappears leaving only the submit button and the search results

**Here is the dictionary/form code**

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label=False)
```

**the dictionary/view code**

```
def index(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
       
        if form.is_valid():
            word = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
            print(word)
            

            if Dictionary.get_verb(word):
                verb = Dictionary.get_verb(word)
            else:
                verb = False
            print(verb)

            if  Dictionary.get_noun(word):
                noun = Dictionary.get_noun(word)
            else:
                noun = False
            print(noun)

            synonyms = Dictionary.get_synonyms(word)
            print(synonyms)

            form = NameForm()

            context = {
                'verb':verb,
                'noun':noun,
                'synonyms':synonyms,
            }

            return render(request,'index.html' ,context)
    else:
        form = NameForm()

        context = {
            'form': form,
        }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**and the index.html**

```
form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<hr>
{% if noun %}
<h2>Noun</h2>
    {% for noun_word in noun %}
        <p>{{noun_word}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<!--   print nothing-->
{% endif %}

<br>
<hr>
{% if verb %}
<h2>Verb</h2>
    {% for verb_info in verb %}
        <p>{{verb_info}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <!--   print nothing-->
{% endif %}


<h2>Synonyms</h2>
{% if synonyms %}
    {% for synonym_info in synonyms %}
       <p>{{synonym_info}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <!--   print nothing-->
{% endif %}
```

I have created a dictionary class to interact with the Dictionary API. But my challenge is how do i go about it so that when the form is submitted it will return the form and the button together with the results below. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the form in context when the form is valid, that's why it is `disappearing`.

```
form = NameForm()

context = {
     'verb': verb,
     'noun': noun,
     'synonyms': synonyms,
     'form': form  ## missing this (add)
}
return render(request,'index.html' ,context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add render in forms.py or you can set the action in your template

```
<form class="postForm" action="{% url 'name of your url' %}" method="POST">
```